# Altair: Disable the "Open in Vega Editor" option in a Colab / jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, altair, vega-lite, vega-embed

When using JS to render a `vega-lite` chart that was originally built in Python (using `altair`), the default is to allow a variety of options on the chart itself: save as image, view source, and Open in Vega Editor.

Using this method, we can modify those options by adjusting the [`vega-embed` "actions" option](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed/blob/master/README.md#options):

```json
"actions": {"editor": false}
```

Eg:

```js
var spec = JSON.parse({{ graph_json|tojson }})
var opt = {   /* Options for the embedding */
  "renderer": "canvas",
  "actions": {
    "export": true,    /* "Save as PNG|SVG" */
    "source": true,    /* "View Source" */
    "compiled": true,  /* "View Vega Source" */
    "editor": false    /* Do not allow export to https://vega.github.io/editor */
  }
};
vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, opt);
```

However, when using `altair` in a colab / Jupyter Notebook, we don't have access to that JS. Is there a way to modify those options using `altair` directly?

I was thinking there might be a [renderer option](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html#renderer-api), but I haven't been able to find anything. Perhaps there's a way to [customize the colab renderer](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/custom_renderers.html)?

---

Alternatively, how about setting `editorUrl`?

#### But why do I want to do this?

TL;DR: Data exfiltration risk.

Disabling those "Show Source" and "Editor" buttons is one part of data exfil protection. Using a self-hosted editor instead of the default github one is another acceptable method.

Answer (score 2):

Altair [2.3.0 (2018-12-07)](https://altair-viz.github.io/releases/changes.html?highlight=set_embed_options#version-2-3-0-released-december-7-2018) added the mostly-undocumented `set_embed_options()` method to renderers, which means you can send any args to vega-embed.

Usage:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3], "y": [1, 2, 3]})
alt.renderers.set_embed_options(actions={"editor": False})
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(...)
```

```py
alt.renderers.set_embed_options(editorUrl="http://localhost:8080")
```